# Making a calculator in python

Tags: python, input, python-2.x

So i Tried using this chunk of code to create a calculator in python, since I have just started learning. Thing is, it always says I enter an invalid option, passing through all my if-else statements, even when I do enter a valid option. What did I do wrong ?

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

def add():
    return float(input ("Enter a number: ")) + float(input ("Enter another number: "))

def subt():
    return float(input ("Enter a number: ")) - float(input ("Enter another number: "))

def mult():
    return float(input ("Enter a number: ")) * float(input ("Enter another number: "))

def power():
    return float(input ("Enter a number: ")) ** float(input ("Enter another number: "))

def division():
    return float (input ("Enter a number: ")) / float (input ("Enter another number: "))

s = input("Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide or Power two Numbers: ")
if s == "add":
    print(add ())
elif s == "subtract":
    print(subt ())
elif s == "multiply":
    print(mult ())
elif s == "power":
    print(power ())
elif s == "division":
    print(division ())
else:
    print ("Enter a valid option")
```

Comment: Try `s = input("Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide or Power two Numbers: ").strip().lower()`

Comment: Just tried your code and it works for me. `Python3.7`

Comment: A good tip for you to use, do `print(repr(s))` and see what the value `s` actually contains. And you can use this on literally any variable/data you're not sure of why things aren't behaving as you'd expect. Later on, you can do `print(s == "multiply")` to see if that statement is `True` or `False`, that way, you know for sure that the block you expected to enter - isn't behaving as expected. **always** print (or debug) your values, odds are the thing in your variable isn't what you think it is.. so print it and show yourself it. Also, Python is case sensitive ;)

Comment: Works for me, but is case sensitive, add != Add

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: I just tried the repr(s) and it prints "<function add at 0x7f8ebd57c668>
"

Comment: Then the code you have above, is not the code you're running on. Because that sounds to me like you did `print(repr(add))`, or you're running python two. Use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`

Comment: kill your kernal, then run code again.

Comment: @DeltaXGamerPT oh and move to python 3 if you dont specifically need to use 2. They have some key differences, and if you're starting fresh, 3 is the way to go.

Comment: You can make your life easier by changing the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/python3` and simply do `./yourscript.py`. Or do `python3 yourscript.py` as you probably already are.

Comment: I already updated my Python version, read that I could do it even tho Ubuntu runs a 2.something Version of python, is there any problem with that alternative ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If sounds like you're using Python2. In that case, use `raw_input` instead of `input`, otherwise it tries to locate a variable/function by the users string input and place the object-name in `s`. Where as `raw_input` takes a user input as a string and places the string `s`.

This is the short answer of the difference between the two.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def add():
    return float(input ("Enter a number: ")) + float(input ("Enter another number: "))

def subt():
    return float(input ("Enter a number: ")) - float(input ("Enter another number: "))

def mult():
    return float(input ("Enter a number: ")) * float(input ("Enter another number: "))

def power():
    return float(input ("Enter a number: ")) ** float(input ("Enter another number: "))

def division():
    return float (input ("Enter a number: ")) / float (input ("Enter another number: "))

s = raw_input("Add, Subtract, Multiply, Divide or Power two Numbers: ")
if s == "add":
    print(add())
elif s == "subtract":
    print(subt())
elif s == "multiply":
    print(mult())
elif s == "power":
    print(power())
elif s == "division":
    print(division())
else:
    print("Enter a valid option")
```

There's a lot of differences in Python2 and Python3, specifying which one you're using helps a lot. It either says it at the top of your terminal when you enter the python interpreter or if you execute `python --version`.

Comment: Yes ! Just checked and my python version is 2.7 ! Thank you !

Comment: You're welcome @DeltaXGamerPT, don't forget to mark the answer as the solution if it helped you. Welcome to stack overflow. And don't forget, Python is case sensitive - so doing `s.lower() == "subtract"` is pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import*

def btnClick(numbers): 
    global operator 
    operator = operator + str(numbers) 
    text_Input.set(operator)

def btnClearDisplay(): 
    global operator 
    operator = "" text_Input.set("")

def btnEqualsInput(): 
    global operator 
    sumup = str(eval(operator)) 
    text_Input.set(sumup) 
    operator=""

cal = Tk() 
cal.title("Suhail calculator") 
operator = "" 
text_Input = StringVar() 
txtDisplay = Entry(cal, font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), textvariable=text_Input, bd=30, insertwidth=4, bg="powder blue", justify='right').grid(columnspan=4)

btn7 = Button(cal, padx=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), text="7", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:btnClick(7)).grid(row=1, column=0)

btn8 = Button(cal, padx=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), text="8", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:btnClick(8)).grid(row=1, column=1)

btn9 = Button(cal, padx=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), text="9", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:btnClick(9)).grid(row=1, column=2)

addition = Button(cal, padx=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial',20,'bold'), text="+", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:btnClick("+")).grid(row=1, column=3) #================================================================================ 
btn4 = Button(cal, padx=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), text="4", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:btnClick(4)).grid(row=2, column=0)

btn5 = Button(cal, padx=16, bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), text="5", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:btnClick(5)).grid(row=2, column=1)

btn6 = Button(cal, padx=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), text="6", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:btnClick(6)).grid(row=2, column=2)

subtraction = Button(cal, padx=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), text="-", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:btnClick("-")).grid(row=2, column=3) #================================================================================= 
btn1 = Button(cal, padx=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), text="1", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:btnClick(1)).grid(row=3, column=0)

btn2 = Button(cal, padx=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), text="2", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:btnClick(2)).grid(row=3, column=1)

btn3 = Button(cal, padx=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), text="3", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:btnClick(3)).grid(row=3, column=2)

multiply = Button(cal, padx=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), text="", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:btnClick("")).grid(row=3, column=3)

#=================================================================================== 
btn0 = Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), text="0", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:btnClick(0)).grid(row=4, column=0)

btnClear = Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), text="C", bg="powder blue", command=btnClearDisplay).grid(row=4, column=1)

btnEqual = Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), text="=", bg="powder blue", command=btnEqualsInput).grid(row=4, column=2)

Division = Button(cal, padx=16, pady=16, bd=8, fg="black", font=('arial', 20, 'bold'), text="/", bg="powder blue", command=lambda:btnClick("/")).grid(row=4, column=3) #==================================================================================

cal.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to StackOverflow!  Thank you for offering us your code; it could use a bit of explanation -- is this an answer to the original poster's question?  There is already an accepted answer; could you explain what your answer adds that is not yet covered?  It is not clear to me.